# Htmlspecialchar in twig

Tags: twig

I have a  [problem with Htmlspecialchar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld7Ef.png)on twig I have this

```
` <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ form_row(formEdit.description) }}
        </div>
    </div>`
```

I checked the twig documentation I found,  I tried to fix it by adding (raw)

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        {{ form_row(formEdit.description|raw) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/autoescape.html for enabling or disabling autoescaping, and https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/striptags.html to remove tags (which is shown on you screenshot)

Comment: it removes the tags but I can't edit anymore the text and show those character (Déscription&lt;div&gt;&lt;strong&gt;A p) I tried with auto escape but it doesn't work

Comment: You should look into `form_row` macro. The fact you can't edit the text has nothing to do with escaping

Comment: What **exactly** is "the problem"?

Comment: in the Enterprise Entity I created a CRUD to manipulate it's offers for editing an offer I get  it's description with tags (I tried  with autoescape(but doesn't have any effect)  I added     {{ form_row(formEdit.description)|**striptags**}} and I have the same problem like ":Déscription&lt;div&gt;&lt;strong&gt;A propos&lt;br&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Au Fil de l’Eau, association nationale de jeunesse et d’éducation populaire, agit dans le domaine du tourisme fluvial, de l’insertion par l’activité économique, et du développement soutenable des activités en lien "

Comment: I don't use CkEditor it can be the problem ?